# Hashmap with a .class object as a key

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I've created a hashmap with .class objects for keys.

```
Hashmap<Class<? extends MyObject>, Object> mapping = new Hashmap<Class<? extends MyObject>, Object>();
```

This is all well and fine, but I'm getting strange behaviour that I can only attribute to strangeness with the hash function. Randomly during runtime, iterating through the hashmap will not hit every value; it will miss one or two. I think this may be due to the .class object not being final, and therefore it changes causing it to map to a different hash value. With a different hash value, the hashmap wouldn't be able to correctly correlate the key with the value, thus making it appear to have lost the value.

Am I correct that this is what is going on? How can I work around this? Is there a better way to accomplish this form of data structure?

Edit: I really thought I was onto something with the hash function thing, but I'll post my real code to try and figure this out. It may be a problem with my implementation of a multimap. I've been using it for quite some time and haven't noticed any issues until recently.

```
/**
 * My own implementation of a map that maps to a List. If the key is not present, then
 * the map adds a List with a single entry. Every subsequent addition to the key
 * is appended to the List.
 * @author 
 *
 * @param <T>   Key
 * @param <K>   Value
 */

public class MultiMap<T, K> implements Map<T, List<K>>, Serializable, Iterable<K> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5789101682525659411L;

    protected HashMap<T, List<K>> set = new HashMap<T, List<K>>();

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        set = new HashMap<T, List<K>>();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object arg0) {
        return set.containsKey(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object arg0) {
        boolean output = false;

        for(Iterator<List<K>> iter = set.values().iterator();iter.hasNext();) {
            List<K> searchColl = iter.next();
            for(Iterator<K> iter2 = searchColl.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();) {
                K value = iter2.next();
                if(value == arg0) {
                    output = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<T, List<K>>> entrySet() {

        Set<Entry<T, List<K>>> output = new HashSet<Entry<T,List<K>>>();

        for(Iterator<T> iter1 = set.keySet().iterator(); iter1.hasNext();) {
            T key = iter1.next();
            for(Iterator<K> iter2 = set.get(key).iterator(); iter2.hasNext();) {
                K value = iter2.next();
                List<K> input = new ArrayList<K>();
                input.add(value);
                output.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<T,List<K>>(key, input));
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return set.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<T> keySet() {
        return set.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return set.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<List<K>> values() {
        Collection<List<K>> values = new ArrayList<List<K>>();
        for(Iterator<T> iter1 = set.keySet().iterator(); iter1.hasNext();) {
            T key = iter1.next();
            values.add(set.get(key));
        }
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public List<K> get(Object key) {
        return set.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public List<K> put(T key, List<K> value) {
        return set.put(key, value);
    }

    public void putValue(T key, K value) {
        if(set.containsKey(key)) {
            set.get(key).add(value);
        }
        else {
            List<K> setval = new ArrayList<K>();
            setval.add(value);
            set.put(key, setval);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<K> remove(Object key) {
        return set.remove(key);
    }

    public K removeValue(Object value) {
        K valueRemoved = null;
        for(T key:this.keySet()) {
            for(K val:this.get(key)) {
                if(val.equals(value)) {
                    List<K> temp = this.get(key);
                    temp.remove(value);
                    valueRemoved = val;
                    this.put(key, temp);
                }
            }
        }
        return valueRemoved;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends T, ? extends List<K>> m) {
        for(Iterator<? extends T> iter = m.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            T key = iter.next();
            set.put(key, m.get(key));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<K> iterator() {
        return new MultiMapIterator<K>(this);
    }
}
```

Perhaps there is an issue with my iterator? I'll post that code as well.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class MultiMapIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private MultiMap <?, T> map;
    private Iterator<List<T>> HashIter;
    private Iterator<T> govIter;
    private T value;
    public MultiMapIterator(MultiMap<?, T> map) {
        this.map = map;
        HashIter = map.values().iterator();
        if(HashIter.hasNext()) {
            govIter = HashIter.next().iterator();
        }
        if(govIter.hasNext()) {
            value = govIter.next();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (govIter.hasNext()) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(HashIter.hasNext()) {
            govIter = HashIter.next().iterator();
            return this.hasNext();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if(!this.hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        else {
            value = govIter.next();
            return value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        map.remove(value);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long tracts of code. Thank you for spending time helping me with this.

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE.

Comment: A `Class` instance should hash correctly, being an object representing a class. Could there be a threading issue in your code?

Comment: It's all on one thread as far as I know. It's through a server that doesn't allow asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Then I suggest you do as [Puce](http://stackoverflow.com/users/506855/puce) says.

Comment: Puce, I will need a moment to whip something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pull the a value out of `govIter` in the constructor, but never return it.

Your iterator remove method is completely wrong.  You are iterating *values*, but calling the `map.remove` which removes by *key*.  you simply want to call `govIter.remove()` (unless you need to avoid empty lists, in which case it's more complicated).

Your hasNext() method could also have problems depending on whether or not you allow empty Lists values in your multimap.

Comment: Ok, I'll make those changes and see what I can fix. More than likely this is an issue with my mutli-map then, which is a relief.